# Unexpected result of javascript indexOf() method in strict mode

Tags: javascript, arrays, indexof, mode, strict

I can't understand why the result of code execution gonna be `-1` (in strict mode only):

```
'use strict'
[0,1].indexOf(0)
```

Is it bug or there is some other reason?
Note: in normal mode it works as expected: index of 0 is `0`

I try to analyze [Polyfills code on mdn](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/indexOf) and have just one idea why it can happen: in strict mode in some cases `this` is not refer to window, but to 'undefined'.

Answer (score 4):

It is more like how the engine is evaluating your code.

The browser is seeing it as one line, not two

```
'use strict'[0,1].indexOf(0)
```

which evaluates to

```
's'.indexOf(0)
```

which is -1

Now if you ran that same code with a semicolon, you would get 0

```
'use strict';
[0,1].indexOf(0)
```

Comment: Correct, you could add that he has to add a semicolon after `'use strict'` to make it to work. Edit: see you have already added that.

Answer (score 1):

ASI kicks you.

```js
'use strict'; // NB
[0,1].indexOf(0)
```